# sign-up pop-up on webform

Tags: webforms, javascript

I'm going to make a sign-up website. When the user has clicked on Sign-up link it will take them to this pop-up window on the browser itself giving them one option (to input mail) then a submit button. I know how to setup the thing in webform but how do I make a sweet pop-up window for the user to enter the value? Is there any module for this?

Any suggestions are welcome

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Modal Form](https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms) Module supports modal window for `webform`, you can also use [shadowbox](https://drupal.org/project/shadowbox) module which creates a modal window for anything.